# Is the aliquot sum of an odd number always odd?

Tags: divisor-sum

I am thinking yes.  Here's my reasoning:

Let $s(x)$ be the [aliquot sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) of $x$.

If $p$ is prime then $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x) + x$

Base Case: if $x$ is an odd prime, then $s(x) = 1$

Assume it is true up to $x$ so that $s(x)$ is odd.

Inductive Case:  $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x) + x =$ odd + odd + odd = odd.

I checked the Wikipedia article on aliquot sum, but I didn't see this as a property.

Comment: The square of a squarefree odd composite will give a counter example. Try $225$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square numbers are a special case.